# How does a WebSocket client know a message has been read completely?

Tags: go, websocket

I used do it like:

```golang
    ...
    ws, err := websocket.Dial(url, "", origin)
    ...
    var buffer = make([]byte, 512)
    var rs = make([]byte, 0, 512)
L:
    for {
        m, err := ws.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break L
            }
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            return
        }
        rs = append(rs, buffer[:m]...)
        if m < 512 {
            break L
        }
    }
```

This has a bug: if the message's length is exactly 512 or 1024 or 2048... the loop never breaks; it will be stuck at `ws.Read()` and wait without throwing `io.EOF`.

Afterwards I observed that `ws.Len()` is always longer than the messages's length by 4.

I rewrote the code as:

```golang
    var buffer = make([]byte, 512)
    var rs = make([]byte, 0, 512)
    var sum = 0
L:
    for {
        m, err := ws.Read(buffer)
        if err != nil {
            if err == io.EOF {
                break L
            }
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
            return
        }
        rs = append(rs, buffer[:m]...)
        sum+=m
        if sum >= ws.Len()-4 {
            break L
        }
    }
```

This way is okay.

But the number `4` is a magic code.

Is there a way to find the message's max length?

Some friends suggest separating the message packet, but I think WebSocket should not consider packet stucking or separating.

What is the most proper way for a WebSocket client to read a message?

Comment: what is the package that u used for this web socket connection?

Comment: @ASHWINRAJEEV "golang.org/x/protobuf/proto"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the golang.org/x/net/websocket package. It's not possible to reliably detect message boundaries using that package's Read method.

To fix, use [websocket.Message](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket#Message) to read messages.

```
var msg string
err := websocket.Message.Receive(ws, &msg)
if err != nil {
  // handle error
}
// msg is the message
```

Note that the [golang.org/x/net/websocket documentation](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/websocket) says:

> This package currently lacks some features found in an alternative and more actively maintained WebSocket package:
>
> https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket

The Gorilla [documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/websocket) and [examples](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples) show how to read messages.